# How to drop duplicates from list with some condition, underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I try to remove duplicate objects by email but with some condition.

Consider I have following list of objects:

```
var contacts = [{
    "email": {
        "value": "email1@gmail.com"
      }
  },
  {
    "displayName": "name 1",
    "email": {
        "value": "email1@gmail.com"
      }
  }
];
```

I have 600 items and I want to drop all duplicates **BUT** if I have for example 2 items with the same email but in one item I have `displayName` and in other no such field -> leave item with `displayName`.

```
 contacts = _.unique(contacts, function(contact){
    return contact.email.value;
 });
```

This is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/2881/) I play with

Please help,

Comment: What if there are three items and two of them have `displayName`?

Comment: @ thefourtheye take 1st with name. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged underscore, I am giving you the solution with just functions.

```
console.log(_.chain(contacts)
    .groupBy(function(contact) {
        return contact.email.value;
    })
    .values()
    .map(function(contacts) {
        var parts = _.partition(contacts, _.partial(_.has, _, 'displayName'));
        return parts[parts[0].length ? 0 : 1][0];
    })
    .value()
);
# [ { displayName: 'name 1', email: { value: 'email1@gmail.com' } } ]
```

It first groups all the contacts based on the `email.value` and then it picks only the `values` of the key-value pair grouping. It then partitions each of the groups based on the fact that they have `displayName` property or not. If the current group has it then return the first item from the first partition otherwise from the second.

Answer (score 0):

Another way which avoid the whole scan in **partition**:

```
var contacts = [{
    "email": {
        "value": "email1@gmail.com"
      }
  },
  {
    "displayName": "name 1",
    "email": {
        "value": "email1@gmail.com"
      }
  },
  {
    "displayName": "name 2",
    "email": {
        "value": "email2@gmail.com"
      }
  }
];

var filteredContacts =
    _.chain(contacts)
    .groupBy( // group contacts by email
        function(contact) { return contact.email.value; }
    )
    .values()
    .map(
        function(email_contacts) {
            return _.find( // find the first contact with the *displayName* property...
                email_contacts,
                function(contact) { return contact.displayName; }
            ) || email_contacts[0] // ... or return the first contact
        }
    )
    .value();

// returns
// [
//   {
//     "displayName": "name 1",
//     "email": {
//       "value": "email1@gmail.com"
//     }
//   },
//   {
//     "displayName": "name 2",
//     "email": {
//       "value": "email2@gmail.com"
//     }
//   }
```